# sum of the modulus eigenvalues of a matrix A >= B.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-graph-theory

Kindly help me to prove/disprove the following statement.
 
Let $A$ be a symmetric matrix of order $n \times n$ with all the diagonal entry equal to $0$, and other non-diagonal entry equal to $k$ (where $k$ is a fixed positive integer). Similarly,
Let $B$ be a symmetric matrix of order $n \times n$ with all the diagonal entry equal to $0$, and other non-diagonal entry equal to $\ell$ (where $1\leq \ell \leq k<n$).
**For example**:$ A= \begin{pmatrix} \begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 3 & 3 & 3 \\
 3 & 0 & 3 & 3 \\
 3 & 3 & 0 & 3 \\
 3 & 3 & 3 & 0 \\
\end{array}\end{pmatrix}$, 
$B=\begin{pmatrix}
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 3 & 1 & 2 \\
 3 & 0 & 2 & 3 \\
 1 & 2 & 0 & 1 \\
 2 & 3 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\end{pmatrix}$.
Prove/disprove the following statement: 
**Suppose $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, ..., \lambda_n$ are eigenvalues of $A$ and $\mu_1, \mu_2, ..., \mu_n$ are eigenvalues of $B$. Then  $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}{|\lambda_i|}\geq \sum_{i=1}^{n}{|\mu_i|}.$$**
 Note that $A$ and $B$ are the distance matrices of some vertices(diameteral) of $G_1$ and $G_2$ respectively.

Comment: First of all, note that $A$ will always have eigenvalue $k(n-1)$ with multiplicity $1$ and $-k$ with multiplicity $n-1$.  So, the sum of the absolute value of its eigenvalues will always be $2k(n-1)$.

Comment: Yes, but how can we show that for B its less than $2k(n−1)$

Comment: Not sure, just an observation.  Another thing that's worth noting is that it's fairly easy to show that $A$ maximizes $\sum |\lambda_i|^2$ under these constraints, but I don't see how that fact can be leveraged.

Comment: It might be fruitful to attack this geometrically by comparing the surfaces defined by the related quadratic forms.